# Error in running my java project in eclipse

Tags: error-handling

I installed `Eclipse Luna` with `jdk v1.8` and `tomcat 8.5`, for the 1st week I was very good later, then when I tried to run a Java project it is displaying this error:

```
Server tomcatv8.5 server at localhost failed to start
```

Later I deleted the server and again I added a new server, even I changed the port numbers also I deleted the eclipse and tomcat again but the error is still continued to be happen.

How to fix this?